# wxGetElapsedTime function in wxWidgets 2.9+

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I'm trying to follow some old C++ tutorial which use old version o wxWidgets framework (2.6 I think), but I have complied version 2.9.1, where I could not find `wxGetElapsedTime()` and `wxStartTimer()` methods.

The elapsed time method is used as argument to `srand()` method to 'randomize' initial random seed value and the author of the tutorial use after that `wxStartTimer()` to reset timer to zero (instead of use `wxGetElapsedTime(true)`).

```
srand(wxGetElapsedTime(false));
wxStartTimer();
```

After some search on Google I found, that those methods are deprecated, but I could not find some clue which functions are used in 2.9+ wxWidgets instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
srand((int)wxGetLocalTime());
```

and

```
wxStopWatch * stopWatch = new wxStopWatch();

updateSomethingByTime( stopWatch->Time() );
```

Comment: I found, that `wxTimer` have `start()` method, which does same thing as old `wxStartTimer()` method, and I did used `wxGetLocalTime()` for seed number generation. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could try the wxStopWatch class it has methods like those for measuring times. Not sure how you'd get the system uptime for seeding srand() though, although you could get the current time from wxDateTime and use that.